# Angularjs .then is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to call a Factory method from a Controller method in Angular. But when I call the Factory method `AuthFactory.login(username,password).then()`, it shows Error like this

```
TypeError: AuthFactory.login(...).then is not a function
```

[Plunker code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HZFHqa1dxn0uMmqKmpFV?p=preview) .

I think I am missing here a concept of AngularJS promises.

Comment: exactly, you are missing a promise which should be returned for you to be able to use the `.then` - if you can post the factory, we may be able to help you put that in (it's pretty easy, but the docs are terrible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For login method, you are sending simple javascript `object` not `promise` object.

```
function login(username, password) {
    var userInfo = {
      "authToken": "6a65dd0c-b35a-429b-a9c0-f5c327ec5d6f",
      "id": "1445138519"
    };
    return userInfo; // Returning javascript object
}
```

In plunkr, you have some commented code as below:

```
 // $http.post(API_URL + '/auth/login', {
 //   email: username,
 //   password: password
 // })
```

So instead returning `userInfo`, return `$http.post` object and then use `then` method.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the response in a promise, which then resolves.

```
.factory('AuthFactory', function AuthFactory($http, API_URL, $q) {
 'use strict';
 return {
   login: login
 };

 function login(username, password) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  deferred.resolve( 
  {
    "authToken":"6a65dd0c-b35a-429b-a9c0-f5c327ec5d6f",
    "id": "1445138519"
  });
  return deferred.promise;
```

You return the promise, but resolve the actual result. If you want it to fail, you can do a `deferred.reject()` which returns the error condition in your `then`.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EsIHXU8rhqa5XHvRhG6M?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @Incognos for making clear about promises . I am happy that it really worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your are returning an object, not a promise.

If you want to return a promise that resolves to that object is pretty simple:

```
return $q.when(userInfo);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/YeE8JmqcDSKqQY969Kpo?p=preview